# Exercise keeps me in good shape : Is this sentence correct?

Tags: collocations

I've seen this two sentences im my country's English dictionary.

> I exercise every morning to **keep** myself **in good shape.**

---

> It's important for him to **keep in good shape.**

So i became curious if i can use the sentence below :

> Exercise **keeps** me **in good shape.**

Or, should I write the sentence like this? :

> Exercise helps me **keep in good shape.**

Answer (score 1):

"Exercise keeps me in good shape." would be understood by any native English speaker to mean that you exercise to keep your body fit.

Comment: There was only one result on COCA search, so I thought the sentence was somewhat obscure or incorrect. thanks a lot!